# ES6 import with http/2 and css

Tags: css, ecmascript-6, http2

I've been looking at `http/2` and `spdy` to not bundle my application. It all works fine for `javascript`.

I want to keep `css` as part of a component as well. Is bundling `css` (using `scss`) still the best way to do it?

Comment: Note that spdy is deprecated. H/2 is its evolutionary successor.

Comment: @Rob thanks. I was testing the `spdy` module and it's `h2`. It falls back nicely so I don't have to care... maybe it's not needed today?